# Does it make sense to say $C_c [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

Since $[0,1]$ is a compact space, functions in $C[0,1]$ will all have compact support, so we have $C_c[0,1] = C[0,1]$. The definition of compact support does not require the support to be a proper subset of the domain.

Now, if we want to define test functions $ \mathcal{D}[0,1] = C_c^\infty [0,1]$ then it is not necessarily that the test functions will be zero on the boundary $\{0,1\}$, so how would we define distributional derivative where we want the boundary term to disappear from integration by parts formula, that is (at least for $g\in L^1_{loc})$
$$\int_0^1 g '\phi = -\int_0^1 g\phi'.$$

Comment: It is common to define test functions on an open sets $(0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes, $C([0,1])=C_c([0,1])$. If you look closely at the definition of $\mathcal D(\Omega)$ and $\mathcal D'(\Omega)$ you see that these are defined for $\Omega$ an _open_ set. One does not typically speak of "distributions in $[0,1]$".

Comment: Suppose in a problem with $f\in C[0,1]$ and for an argument I would need to take the weak derivative of the function $f$, how would I go around this problem, can I work with $C(-\epsilon, 1+ \epsilon)$?